Computing shared variances
Suppose I estimate an OLS regression model with 3 correlated explanatory variables. Then I can decompose the explained variances such as in this image:

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/49749932_CORINE_land_cover_and_floristic_variation_in_a_Mediterranean_wetland
How can I compute the SHARED variances? I know how to compute A, B and C as the semipartial correlations². But what about D, E, F, and G? Any advice, especially for Stata, is welcome, thanks!
